# aws datasync cause double trigger for lambda event

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-datasync

I use AWS DataSync service to sync two buckets A and B
The DataSync defined to check integrity during transfer and copy only new data to another bucket (B).

I have lambda function that defined to trigger on new files from bucket B

All files that created via DataSync triggers Lambda two times

I created cloudwatch dashboard to count the files that triggered lambda event and I see it double
[image]
The event for two trigger s is the same "PUT"

```
 'event_time': '2023-02-27T12:46:48.926Z', 'event_source': 'aws:s3', 'aws_region': 'eu-west-1', 'event_name': 'ObjectCreated:Put'}
```

The time stamp almost the same with 2-3 seconds difference

I set number of attempts to 0
I set event timeout lees then lambmda timeout

Nothing helped

Anyone faced same issue and solved it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

After working with AWS Support Engineer from DataSync, we confirmed that it's a thing by design of how DataSync works.

DataSync treats S3 like any other file systems. **Creates file (that 0 Byte object) then uploads data to it (the actual file size object) but since S3 is object storage, it doesn't support in place edits. So there's this second put again.**

> "When using object versioning in Amazon S3, running a DataSync task
> once might create more than one version of an Amazon S3 object."

That's for versioning enabled bucket but we confirmed for versioning disabled bucket as well.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datasync/latest/userguide/create-s3-location.html#create-s3-location-considerations

Unfortunately S3 Event notifications does not have ability to filter/exclude if object size is 0 Byte. So the conclusion for my case was I will have to find workarounds in my downstream processes, e.g. exclude those messages with 0 Byte object size.

---

I'm not able to comment at the moment so I'm just posting here in the answer section (I'll try to complete this as an answer as I do my troubleshooting).

I had the similar issue but it is with SQS as the event notification destination. I enabled the S3 server access log and queried for the requests history, I found that the DataSync job for some reasons made two `REST.PUT.OBJECT` request, and I also noticed that in the second request the objectsize is actually 0, but I think the duplicated request will definitely make S3 deliver the event notification twice. I'm still troubleshooting it now.
[image]

Comment: Thank you
It happens also if you disable the versioning